# non-null variable in flutter test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I was learning flutter about year ago and now im coming back after a break but i counter a problem, it's probalby pretty simple but i dont really understand it.

Im following a tutorial on Flutter Clean Architecture and when i'm writing my first test i have an error says
"The non-nullable local variable 'mockNumberTriviaRepository' must be assigned before it can be used."
I dont know how to write it to be a proper code.

My code is below:

```
class MockNumberTriviaRepository extends Mock
    implements NumberTriviaRepository {}

void main() {
  GetConcreteNumberTrivia usecase;
  MockNumberTriviaRepository mockNumberTriviaRepository;

  setUp(() {
    MockNumberTriviaRepository mockNumberTriviaRepository = MockNumberTriviaRepository();
    usecase = GetConcreteNumberTrivia(mockNumberTriviaRepository);
  });

  final tNumber = 1;
  final tNumberTrivia = NumberTrivia(number: 1, text: 'test');
  test('schould get trivia for the number from the repository', () async {
    // arrange
    when(**mockNumberTriviaRepository**.getConcreteNumberTrivia(1)).thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tNumberTrivia));
    // act

    // assert
  });
}
```

Error appears in part between ** ** this signs after the when method in test function

Answer (score 4):

The compiler can't really understand that you're initializing the value later. To tell it that you promise to do so before using the variable, add `late` keyword before the type.

Example:

```dart
// compiles successfully and prints 'abc'
void main() {
  late String foo;
  
  (){
    foo = 'abc';
  }();

  print(foo);
}
```

In your case it will be

```dart
late MockNumberTriviaRepository mockNumberTriviaRepository;
```

Answer (score 2):

At the top of void main initialize the mockNumberTriviaRepository as

`MockNumberTriviaRepository mockNumberTriviaRepository= MockNumberTriviaRepository();`

```
class MockNumberTriviaRepository extends Mock
    implements NumberTriviaRepository {}

void main() {
  GetConcreteNumberTrivia usecase;
  MockNumberTriviaRepository mockNumberTriviaRepository= MockNumberTriviaRepository();

  setUp(() {
   //MockNumberTriviaRepository mockNumberTriviaRepository = MockNumberTriviaRepository();
    usecase = GetConcreteNumberTrivia(mockNumberTriviaRepository);
  });

  final tNumber = 1;
  final tNumberTrivia = NumberTrivia(number: 1, text: 'test');
  test('schould get trivia for the number from the repository', () async {
    // arrange
    when(**mockNumberTriviaRepository**.getConcreteNumberTrivia(1)).thenAnswer((_) async => Right(tNumberTrivia));
    // act

    // assert
  });
}
```

or use late keyword

```
late MockNumberTriviaRepository mockNumberTriviaRepository;
```